# Do I have a cracked launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

So I read somewhere that there is something called a cracked launcher but how do I know if I have one? Because someone said that if one has a cracked launcher they are unable to connect to servers. I don't know how to check if I have a cracked launcher.

Comment: If you downloaded the launcher from anywhere else except the [Official Minecraft Website](https://minecraft.net/en-us/0) then its potentially a cracked one.

Answer (score 8):

If you believe you have a cracked launcher, you may also have a pirated copy of Minecraft.

The first question to ask yourself is:

*Did I buy Minecraft from the official site and can otherwise launch it without downloading a separate piece of software?*

If the answer is no to either question, the potential for a cracked / pirated copy is between *high* to *guaranteed*.

Cracked launchers are most easily identified by the look and title of the launcher used to launch Minecraft.

The official Minecraft Launcher says *Minecraft Launcher*, but may have launcher versions appended to its name.

[image: Official Minecraft Launcher]

[image: Official beta Minecraft Launcher]

Cracked launchers may look similar but are called something else.

[image: you can see in the upper left of the window, a name other than Minecraft Launcher]

Most servers block cracked launcher / pirated version of Minecraft connection because the launcher changes the internet connection to `null` (among other changes in the settings)

Many forums dedicated to Minecraft exist. In each is almost invariably a very open and public discussion regarding ways thr general community handles pirated copies of the game and the various ways attempts are made to play. The few servers that *do* allow connection aren't too kind in their plans and examples. There are ever evving ways to thwart piracy due to the popularity of ethical players, which can account for the declining success of cracked and pirated copies appearing on servers.

Additionally, ethical server hosts and minecraft.net will take a degree of action regarding an account up to and including blacklisting computer IP when cracked and pirated copies are discovered.

Just remember, Minecraft is rated E-10, not "Arrrrrrr."